# Is there a way to find out HTTP Post parameter names when you don't have the form?

Tags: php, http, post, httprequest, post-parameter

There is a php web page that i want to submit my POST request but i don't know the name of the parameter. Is there a way to find out the name of the parameter that i should submit my values into.

Update: I don't have the form that submit to that page. So i can't use $_POST.

Comment: Why would you want to post if you don't even know what the receiving page is expecting? Sounds like you want to spam and can't be bothered to analyze the form.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the names of all passed `$_POST` parameters with:

```
$parameter_names = array_keys($_POST);
```

If you know there is only one parameter, to get the value use:

```
$value = $_POST[array_keys($_POST)[0]];
```

Comment: The question is unclear, but doesn't mention the page is accepting post data, but is submitting post data to a page so this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: I see, I guess you can interpret it like that.

Comment: Also this snippet requires at least PHP 5.4.

Comment: PHP 5.3 was deprecated 6 days ago. http://php.net/eol.php I considered adding it.

Comment: The page accepts 1 post parameter. That is given

Comment: The problem is that i don't have the form used to submit to that page.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Find the form, and 'fake' it if you need to. You seem to be faking a form you can't find? Makes no sens.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know the parameters and don't programmatically use them, you can also use `print_r($_POST);`

Comment: This is a good suggestion. `var_dump` does a similar job, it also gives you information about the type of variable. One reason to use `print_r` over `var_dump` is that the former can print recursive structures.

Comment: They all do that, of course. http://3v4l.org/LIk8U The main advantage of `print_r()` IMO is readability.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to submit data to a form, but don't know what keys to use to submit. As you know, you need to know them, so find the form on the website, and look at the source code for the `name="whatever"` parts of the relevant inputs and make a note of the string inside the quotes. Those are your key names.

Comment: Yeah.. but thats the problem.. i can't find the form... You described my scenario. Is there anyway to do it?

Comment: It's great that the person who understood the question is sitting on a downvote, whilst the other answers are not useful with positive scores! @MuhammadIbraheem that's like asking how to walk across the street. Some journeys you have to tread by yourself.